# Modelling samples with complex unsure distribution origin using PyMC

Tags: pymc

I've been learning PyMC for the last couple of days and have been trying to model the following problem:

I have got a number of effectors that regulate targets with known values. For some targets the effector is known, but for others they are only partially known. The total number of effectors and targets is large, so I can't simply enumerate them in my code (or use a Bernoulli distribution with uniform prior). You can think of the targets to be samples from **one** effector (Normal) distribution.

As an example, let's assume we have got the effectors E1 and E2 and the targets T1, T2, and T3. We know that:

```
E1 -> T1, T2
E2 -> T2, T3
```

which means that E1 is regulating T1 and E2 is regulating T3 (i.e., T1 is sampled from E1 and T3 is sampled from E2). For T2, we don't know if it is regulated by/sampled from E1 or E2, so I think it makes sense to use a categorical distribution with a Dirichlet prior.

One idea was to model the data set analogous to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46626/fitting-model-for-two-normal-distributions-in-pymc) and use one observed `Normal` with a categorical combination of `mu` and `tau` for each effector. In this case:

- for T1, it would be `1*mu(E1) + 0*mu(E2)`
- for T3, it would be `0*mu(E1) + 1*mu(E2)`
- for T2, it would be a Dirichlet with `tau=(1,1)`

But how can I combine this into one framework? An obvious solution would be to use `tau=(1,0)` and `tau=(0,1)` for T1 and T3, but I can't assign zero probabilities in a Dirichlet. I guess I have to modify the `Categorical` to return `0` for not regulating effectors and a Dirichlet of all possible effectors (or modify the Dirichlet?) but I'm not sure how to do that.

Another possibility would be to model each `E` as a `Normal` and assign uncertain origin to each value of `T`, but I don't know if that's possible.

Any ideas?